# How to add the removed space in a sentence?

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following string:

```
x = "marchTextIWantToDisplayWithSpacesmarch"
```

I would like to delete the 'march' portion at the beginning of the string and then add a space before each uppercase letter in the remainder to yield the following result:

```
"Text I Want To Display With Spacesmarch"
```

To insert whitepace, I used `gsub("([a-z]?)([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2", x, perl= T)` but I have no clue how to modify the pattern so that the first 'march' is excluded from the returned string. I'm trying to get better at this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may use one regex but with `trimws`: `trimws(gsub("^\\p{Ll}+|(?!^)(?=\\p{Lu})", " ", x, perl=TRUE))`. Or, you may use a single call to `stringr::str_replace_all` with a similar regex and a callback (here, some custom replacement logic will be necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't achieve your replacement using single `gsub` because in one of your requirement, you want to remove all lowercase letters starting from the beginning, and your second requirement is to introduce a space before every capital letter except the first capital letter of the resultant string after removing all lowercase letters from the beginning of text.

Doing it in single `gsub` call would have been possible in cases where somehow we can re-use some of the existing characters to make the conditional replace which can't be the case here. So in first step, you can use `^[a-z]+` regex to get rid of all lowercase letters only from the beginning of string,

```
sub('^[a-z]+', '', "marchTextIWantToDisplayWithSpacesmarch")
```

leaving you with this,

```
[1] "TextIWantToDisplayWithSpacesmarch"
```

And next step you can use this `(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])` regex to insert a space before every capital letter except the first one as you might not want an extra space before your sentence. But you can combine both and write them as this,

```
gsub('(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', ' ', sub('^[a-z]+', '', "marchTextIWantToDisplayWithSpacesmarch"), perl=TRUE)
```

which will give you your desired string,

```
[1] "Text I Want To Display With Spacesmarch"
```

**Edit:**
Explanation of `(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])` pattern

First, let's just take `(?=[A-Z])` pattern,

**[See the pink markers in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q9Yalc/1/)**

As you can see, in the demo, every capital letter is preceded by a pink mark which is the place where a space will get inserted. But we don't want space to be inserted before the very first letter as that is not needed. Hence we need a condition in regex, which will not select the first capital letter which appears at the start of string. And for that, we need to use a negative look behind `(?<!^)` which means that **Do not select the position which is preceded by start of string** and hence this `(?<!^)` helps in discarding the upper case letter that is preceded by just start of string.

**[See this demo where the pink marker is gone from the very first uppercase letter](https://regex101.com/r/Q9Yalc/2/)**

Hope this clarifies how every other capital letter is selected but not the very first. Let me know if you have any queries further.

Comment: Thanks @Pushpesh. I don't quite understand how the outer gsub works though. I read the pattern as saying 'get all characters that are followed by an uppercase (?=[A-Z]) and are not preceded by the beginning of the string (?<!^)'. But I'm not sure how this ties in with the replacement pattern, would it please be possible to explain this briefly?

Comment: @user51462: Sure, let me add details and demo to clarify it.

Comment: @user51462: I've added the explanation for this `(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])` regex and I hope I was able to clarify. And in case not, please feel free to ask anything further.

Answer (score 5):

An option would be to capture the upper case letter as a group (`(...)`) and in the replacement create a space followed by the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
gsub("([A-Z])", " \\1", x)
#[1] "march Text I Want To Display With Spacesmarch"
```

If we need to remove the 'march'

```
sub("\\b[a-z]\\w+\\s+", "", gsub("([A-Z])", " \\1", x))
[#1] "Text I Want To Display With Spacesmarch"
```

#### data

```
x <- "marchTextIWantToDisplayWithSpacesmarch"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun but I was hoping to learn how to achieve both effects in a single gsub, is that possible? I tried playing around with non-capturing groups like `(?:^[a-z]*)` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a single regex call to `gsub` coupled with `trimws` to trim the resulting string:

```
trimws(gsub("^\\p{Ll}+|(?<=.)(?=\\p{Lu})", " ", x, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "Text I Want To Display With Spacesmarch"
```

It also supports all Unicode lowercase (`\p{Ll}`) and uppercase (`\p{Lu}`) letters.

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/3vmUMj) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Rz5KS/1).

**Details**

- `^\\p{Ll}+` -  1 or more lowercase letters at the string start
- `|` - or
- `(?<=.)(?=\\p{Lu})` - any location between any char but linebreak chars and an uppercase letter.

Here is an altenative with a single call to `gsubfn` regex with some `ifelse` logic:

```
> gsubfn("^\\p{Ll}*(\\p{L})|(?<=.)(?=\\p{Lu})", function(n) ifelse(nchar(n)>0,n," "), x, perl=TRUE,backref=-1) 
[1] "Text I Want To Display With Spacesmarch"
```

Here, the `^\\p{Ll}*(\\p{L})` part matches 0+ lowercase letters and captures the next uppercase into Group 1 that will be accessed by passing `n` argument to the anonymous function. If `n` length is non-zero, this alternative matched and the we need to replace with this value. Else, we replace with a space.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor, the regex demo is very useful. I hadn't thought to use lookarounds. Thanks also for editing the question and removing the erroneous perl tag.

Comment: @user51462 I added a snippet showing how to use a single regex solution with `gsubfn`, too.

Comment: The `gsubfn` solution is closer to what I had in mind since it uses a single regex pattern. I would change the accepted answer to reflect this but I'm not sure if that would be bad etiquette. Thank you for your help nonetheless, I'm fairly new to regular expressions so I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged perl, my 2 cents:

Can you chain together the substitutions inside `sub()` and `gsub()`?  In newer perl versions an `/r` option can be added to the `s///` substitution so the matched string can be returned "non-destructively" and then matched again. This allows hackish match/substitution/rematches without mastering advanced syntax, *e.g.*:

```
perl -E '
  say "marchTextIWantToDisplayWithSpacesmarch" =~
  s/\Amarch//r =~ s/([[:upper:]])/ $1/gr  =~ s/\A\s//r;'
```

**Output**

```
Text I Want To Display With Spacesmarch
```

This seems to be what @pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi and @akrun are doing by wrapping `gsub` inside `sub()` (and vice versa).  In general I don't think`perl = T` captures the full magnificently advanced madness of perl regexps **;-)** but `gsub/sub` must be fast operating on vectors, no?

Comment: It is not about perl, it is a about `perl=TRUE` option in R base regex functions that can use PCRE regex engine. I removed the tag from the question.

Comment: Thanks @G. Cito, my apologies for using the incorrect tag! I don't think the substitutions can be chained in R but it's pretty neat to see how it's done in perl so I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: @user51462 not only can you put one function into the argument of another , as the answers show, but you can pipe stuff in `R` using `magrittr` package.